# One pager - jQuery - mouseenter and mouseleave - skip mouseleave if clicked

Tags: jquery, click, mouseenter, mouseleave

I got a top fixed list navigation in a one pager, works fine.

I've added mouseenter and mouseleave color animation with the jQuery color plugin, works fine too.

Now I want to skip mouseleave, if the link is clicked, but i don't get it. I tried all i've found here but still no result i like. I'm really new JavaScipt / jQuery, so would be kind if you can explain it novice-friendly;).

My navigation html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#leistungen" class="scroll">Leistungen</a></li>
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#referenzen" class="scroll">Referenzen</a></li>
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#me" class="scroll">Über Mich</a></li>
        <li class="xyz"><a href="#kontakt" class="scroll">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My jQuery Code here:

```
$(function() {

$('ul li a.scroll').on('mouseenter', function() { //Wenn Maus über .teaser
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'color': 'white',
        'background-color': '#468592',
    }, 400);
});

$('ul li a.scroll').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'color': '#666666',
            'background-color': 'white',
    }, 400);
});

$('ul li a.scroll').click(function(event) {
    $('.scroll').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);

});
```

});

Can you help me with this problem? I tried it two days now still without a result.

Regards and thanks,
mkr*

Answer (score 1):

In your mouseleave you just need to check if the "active" class exists on the element and do nothing.

```
$('ul li a.scroll').on('mouseleave', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("active"))
        return; // do nothing because it's active
    $(this).stop().animate({
            'color': '#666666',
            'background-color': 'white',
    }, 400);
});
```

**EDIT** Here's a reworked CSS + JS solution. CSS :hover and CSS3 transition are used for the mouse[enter/leave] effect, while JS is used for the click toggling.

http://jsfiddle.net/tdV2g/

You won't get the 0.4second color transition in IE9, but in all modern browsers it will work.

CSS

```
a.scroll {
    background-color: white;
    color: #666666;
transition: background-color 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
}
.scrollactive, a.scroll:hover {
    background-color: #468592;
    color: white;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$("a.scroll").click(function(event) {
    $(".scrollactive")
        .removeClass("scrollactive")
        .addClass("scroll");
    $(this)
        .removeClass("scroll")
        .addClass("scrollactive");
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you!

Now I notice, that clicking on new item doesn't remove the class '.active' from other links? Any help here:)?

Comment: Got it now, just cleared the inline styles:
$('.scroll').css('background-color', '').css('color', '');

Comment: @mkr - glad you figured it out

Comment: Thanks but now I got another problem. You can check here: www.pixelschneiderei.de

When clicking one link and hovering all the other nav links fast some stay in clicked status. Seems like mouseleave doesn't work for them.

Any idea?

Comment: @mkr - you might want to consider using the CSS :hover instead of targeting the mouse[enter/leave] events in your JavaScript. While mouse[enter/leave] should behave predictably I've seen odd quirks when the web page is zoomed or a user has changed mouse sensitivity settings etc.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to smoothly change the color with css? I don't think so. The Zooming issues comes later, just want to test the javascript first. ;)

I don't know what you are meaning with the mouse sensitivity settings?

As always, thanks for your help:)

Comment: @mkr - Yes you can smoothly animate the color with CSS. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

simply add

```
$(this).unbind('mouseleave');
```

inside your `$('ul li a.scroll').click({ .. });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('ul li a.scroll').on('mouseenter', function() { //Wenn Maus über .teaser
  $(this).stop().animate({
    'color': 'white',
    'background-color': '#468592'
  }, 400);

});

$('ul li a.scroll').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'color': '#666666',
        'background-color': 'white'
}, 400);

});


$('ul li a.scroll').one('click', function () {
  // If you want to stop mouseleave on every anchor tag
  $('ul li a.scroll').unbind('mouseleave');  
  // If you want to stop mouseleave for that specific anchor tag
  // $(this).unbind('mouseleave'); 
});
```